# Why is my database not being updated with this LINQ query?

Tags: asp.net, linq

Code:

```
Public Sub UpdateDB()
    Dim db As New linqclassesDataContext
    Dim article = From p In db.articles _
              Where p.id = articlelist.SelectedValue _
              Select p

    article.FirstOrDefault.body = FCKeditor1.Value
    Try
        db.SubmitChanges()
    Catch ex As ChangeConflictException
        fcke_output.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub
```

no errors are thrown, but my database value is not updated. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, make sure the generated class has the primary key attribute.

**Update 1:** linq2sql just doesn't behaves well when no primary key is specified - if there isn't one on the table, make sure to specify an appropiate one on the designer

Comment: being pretty new to LINQ, I am not entirely sure what the "generated class" could be.  could you elaborate please? thanks :)

Comment: Open the dbml file you created, and view the properties of the primary key field. If this isn't set, SubmitChanges will silently fail.